# How to change CSS property using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I want to change a CSS property of a class using JavaScript. What I actually want is when a `<div>` is hovered, another `<div>` should become visible.

```css
.left,
.right {
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px
}

.left:hover,
.right:hover {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.center {
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
  width: 160px
}

.center .left1,
.center .right1 {
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 60px;
  width: 58px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  Hello
</div>
<div class="center">
  <div class="left1">
    Bye
  </div>
  <div class="right1">
    Bye1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  Hello2
</div>
```

When hello1 div is hovered, bye1 div should be visible and similarly bye2 should appear when hello2 is hovered.

Answer (score 121):

You can use `style` property for this. For example, if you want to change border -

```
document.elm.style.border = "3px solid #FF0000";
```

similarly for color -

```
 document.getElementById("p2").style.color="blue";
```

Best thing is you define a class and do this -

`document.getElementById("p2").className = "classname";`

(Cross Browser artifacts must be considered accordingly).

Comment: For updating or adding a new class - document.getElementById("p2").className = "classname"; is not the current way to do it. See this answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/how-can-i-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript

Answer (score 30):

```
// select element from DOM using *const*
const sample = document.getElementById("myid"); // using const
// or you can use *var*
var sample = document.getElementById("myid"); // using var

// change css style
sample.style.color = 'red'; // Changes color, adds style property.
// or (not recomended)
sample.style = "color: red"; // Replaces all style properties. NOT RECOMENDED
```

Answer (score 7):

Consider the following example:
If you want to change a single CSS property(say, color to 'blue'), then the below statement works fine.

```
document.getElementById("ele_id").style.color="blue";
```

But, for changing multiple properies the more robust way is using `Object.assign()` or, `object spread operator {...}`;

### See below:

```
const ele=document.getElementById("ele_id");
const custom_style={
    display: "block",
    color: "red"
}

//Object.assign():
Object.assign(ele.style,custom_style);
```

Spread operator works similarly. The syntax is a little different, that's all.

Answer (score 6):

Use `document.getElementsByClassName('className').style = your_style`.

```
var d = document.getElementsByClassName("left1");
d.className = d.className + " otherclass";
```

**Use single quotes for JS strings contained within an html attribute's double quotes**

**Example**

```
<div class="somelclass"></div>
```

then `document.getElementsByClassName('someclass').style = "NewclassName";`

```
<div class='someclass'></div>
```

then `document.getElementsByClassName("someclass").style = "NewclassName";`

**This is personal experience.**

Comment: There is no such thing as `getElementByClassName`.

Comment: @Derek https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: The point is you forgot an `s` between `Element` and `Class`... It should be `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure single quotes versus double quotes will make no difference in this situation (the browser will interpret them the same; try right-clicking on an element with single quotes and going to "Inspect Element" in Firefox.  You'll find it has double quotes).  The distinction is only worthwhile when you need to nest them, e.g. `document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]')`

Comment: This is still incorrect, `getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements, not a single element. You'd have to iterate over it and apply changes to each of them.

Comment: How does such an utterly wrong answer get so many upvotes?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the info, this can be done with CSS only with just minor HTML and CSS changes

HTML:

```
<div class="left">
    Hello
</div>
<div class="right">
    Hello2
</div>
<div class="center">
       <div class="left1">
           Bye
    </div>
       <div class="right1">
           Bye1
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left, .right{
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:60px;
    width:60px
}
.left:hover, .right:hover{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.right{
     float :right;
}
.center{
    float:left;
    height:60px;
    width:160px
}

.center .left1, .center .right1{
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid green;
    height:60px;
    width:58px;
    display:none;
}
.left:hover ~ .center .left1 {
    display:block;
}

.right:hover ~ .center .right1 {
    display:block;
}
```

and the DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/y8LKM/

Answer (score -5):

This is really easy using jQuery.

For instance:

```
$(".left").mouseover(function(){$(".left1").show()});
$(".left").mouseout(function(){$(".left1").hide()});
```

I've update your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/TqDe9/2/

Comment: This just shows or hides the element, and does not change any css.

Answer (score -6):

You can do so using jQuery like this.

```
$('.left, .right').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    if ($(this).attr('class') == 'left1') {
        $('.left1').css({
            /* 'visibility': 'visible', */
            'display': 'block',
        })
    } else if ($(this).attr('class') == 'left1') {
        $('.right1').css({
            /* 'visibility': 'visible', */
            'display': 'block',
        })
    }
})
```

or you can use it like this

**for first requirement**

```
$('.left').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    $('.left1').css({
        /* 'visibility': 'visible', */
        'display': 'block',
    })
})
```

**for second requirement**

```
$('.right').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    $('.right1').css({
        /* 'visibility': 'visible', */
        'display': 'block',
    })
})
```