# How to set php data to javascript date and change color of the input text

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to change the color of the `input text` whenever the`$visa_expired` is the same date as today. But right now, I get an error saying `Invalid Date`

Here is my code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">


function checkFilled() {

  var today = new Date();
  var expired = new Date("<?php echo $visa_expiry; ?> ");
  var inputVal = document.getElementById("expiry");

    if (inputVal.value == "") {
        inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        window.alert(today);
    }
    else{
        inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
}

checkFilled();

  </script>
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" size="5" value="$visa_expiry" id="expiry">
```

Comment: And what exactly is `$visa_expiry`? Also, why not take the date value from the input field?

Comment: what is the format you are getting the expired date it should be `dateObj = new Date(year, month, date[, hours[, minutes[, seconds[,ms]]]])`

Comment: how can I set the format to that? sorry im new in javascript

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to what I have done in the past

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById("expiry");
var inputDate = inputElement.value;
var expired = new Date();
var today = new Date();

expired.setUTCFullYear(inputDate.split("/")[2], inputDate.split("/")[0] - 1, inputDate.split("/")[1]);


if(today === expired) {
    inputElement.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    window.alert(today);
} else {
    inputElement.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

Also it looks like you need to change

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" size="5" value="$visa_expiry" id="expiry">
```

To

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" size="5" value="<?php echo $visa_expiry; ?>" id="expiry">
```

Just note that since you are using a input form box, its always possible that someone would enter something like 10-12-2016 instead of the 10/12/2016 format you may be expecting. Which would cause the above code to fail. You might want to consider finding a datepicker, or at the least change the
`<input type="text">`
to
`<input type="date">`

Then create some code to format the date to what you want.

References

- [How to change css property using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241915/how-to-change-css-property-using-javascript)
- [Converting string to date in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js)

Answer (score 0):

If 10/13/2016 is the value of $visa_expiry it should not give error.
check this link and run the fiddle it alert date.
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/hpia-ub40

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function checkFilled() {

  var today = new Date();
  var expired = new Date("<?php echo $visa_expiry; ?> ");
  var inputVal = document.getElementById("expiry");

    if (today >= expired) {
        inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    else{
        inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
}

checkFilled();

  </script>
```

Comment: how can I now use my `$visa_expiry`?

Comment: by the way your html should be <input type="text" class="form-control" size="5" value="<?php echo $visa_expiry; ?>" id="expiry">

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to display an Date Object in alert, which expects a string input. You should use `getDate()` instead.

try this:

```
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDate();
var month = today.getMonth() + 1;
var year = today.getFullYear();

today = day + '/' + month + '/' + year
```

Comment: down vote no comment , is this how stackoverflow works?

Comment: the output is number "13"

Comment: may I ask, whats your input (`$visa_expiry`) exactly?

Comment: 10/13/2016. that is the value of `$visa_expiry`

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. `alert(today)` works without a problem. And `getDate()` returns the day of the month.

Comment: what should i do now? @gre_gor

Comment: how can I echo out now my `$visa_expiry` to compare to todays date?