# im having problems to edit css using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

for some reason when i use JavaScript to edit the css of batata[y] nothing happens. The objective of the code is to create multiple blocks and move then from the top to the button of the page.

```js
var p1
var p2 = [];
var y = 0;
var x = 0;
var telaJogo, telaJogo2, telaInicio;
var balao = [];
var a = 0;
var batata;

function ola() {
  var bola = setInterval(addBalao, 1000);
}

function addBalao() {
  telaJogo2 = document.getElementById('telaJogo2');
  p2.push(0);
  balao.push(0);
  p1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 445);
  batata = "balao" + y;
  balao[y] = document.createElement('div'); //create the block
  balao[y].setAttribute("id", batata);
  telaJogo2.appendChild(balao[y]);
  balao[y].style = "top:" + p2[y] + "px;";
  balao[y].style = "left:" + 30 + "px;";
  balao[y].style = "background-color: red;";
  balao[y].style = "height: 50px;";
  balao[y].style = "width: 50px;";
  balao[y].style = "position: absolute";

  console.log("p2[y]" + p2[2]);
  setInterval(ola2, 100);
  y++;
}

function ola2() {
  // move block
  for (x = 0; x < y; x++) {
    p2[x]++;
    atualiza();
  }
  a = 0;
  //console.log(p2);
}

function atualiza() {
  // update the frame
  balao[x].setAttribute("style", "top:" + p2[x] + "px;");
}
```

```css
#telaJogo2 {
  height: 800px;
  width: 445px;
  background-color: #90ee90;
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="ola()">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <div id="telaJogo2">
    <div id="barra1"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please comment your code and format your example as a snippet

Comment: First of all you have errors. There are some comments that are not written as comments. Second, you never called any of your functions so nothing should happen. Please fix your code and edit the post.

Comment: Your code is invalid in the first place.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241915/how-to-change-css-property-using-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change css property using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241915/how-to-change-css-property-using-javascript)

Comment: There's no `batata[y]` in the code, do you mean `balao[y]`?

Comment: Each of your `style` assignments is overwriting the previous one. They don't automatically append. You should assign to `balao[y].style.top`, `balao[y].style.backgroundColor`, etc.