# Why is Chrome reporting element.style rules that are not in my code?

Tags: html, css, dom, inline

One of my divs is having the following rules applied, even though they are not in my CSS, javascript or inline HTML.  The `margin:0px` and `padding:0px` are breaking the layout of the site and I need to override them.  Adding `margin:initial` and `padding:initial` inline to the element in question does not work.

[image]

The actual HTML is below.  The div in question is `col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1`.

```
<section class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1" style="">
                    <div id="ad-middle" class="panel panel-default" style="min-height:320px;">
                        <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0;">                             
                            <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js">
                            </script>
                            <!-- AdSense Responsive -->
                            <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                            style="display:block"
                            data-ad-client="..."
                            data-ad-slot="..."
                            data-ad-format="rectangle"></ins>
                            <script>
                                (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

I am happy to edit the question and provide additional information and code, such as snippets from the CSS files, although they don't contain anything even close to the rules reported by the debugger.

**Edit**:  I can confirm that it's the AdSense code that's altering the styling of the parent div.  I have tried removing the AdSense code from inside the div, and that makes the `margin:0` and `padding:0` rules disappear.  How do I override those rules?

Comment: Did you wrote that part of html or it's generated via a javascript plugin?

Comment: I don't know how it was written originally, but it's part of a static html file, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Then, probably javascript is adding styles. disable javascript in your browser and see what happens. If it's so, you need to change your js file.

Comment: It's the AdSense code inside the div.  I've tested it by removing that code, and the `margin:0` and `padding:0` are gone.  How do I override them?

Comment: Add a script tag right after the line of AdSense script, and override styles there.

Comment: look at this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15241915/6311045)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before doing everything, add an Id to your div "col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1", and then add this script in your html file before closing body tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // you can get element by class name but in this example it's better to get it by Id. so I quote this line.
    // var x = document.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1");

    var x = document.getElementById("adSenseDiv");

    // set your styles inside css variable as below
    var css = {
           color: 'purple',
           background-color: '#e5e5e5',
           height: '150px'
          };
    Object.assign(x.style, css);
</script>
```

or you can add this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">            
        var style = document.createElement('style');

        document.body.appendChild(style);

        // add your styles here
        style.sheet.insertRule('#adSenseDiv {color: darkseagreen}');
    </script>
```