# How do I use the input field in order to change the value of the css property by java script?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, input

I want to enter the value of the property in the entry field, for example color.

And In the other entry field for the new style is blue

```js
let p_change = document.getElementById('p-change');
let property = document.getElementById('property').value; // each color ,fontSize
let newStyle = document.getElementById('style').value;  // each  red , 20px
let change  = document.getElementById('change');

change.onclick = function(){
 p_change.style.property = 'newStyle'; 
}
```

```html
<p id="p-change">Change my style like you love</p>
      <input id="property" value="" placeholder="Enter Property">
    <input id="style" value="" placeholder="Enter New Style">
      <button id="change">Change</button>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovlly.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change css property using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241915/how-to-change-css-property-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the property and the styles after you click the button.

If you get them before, they are empty strings.

Also, use `const` not `let`. No need to use `let` in this case.

Also added a small verification the see if the `property` entered exists or not.

```js
const p_change = document.getElementById('p-change');
const change = document.getElementById('change');

change.onclick = function() {
  const property = document.getElementById('property').value
  const newStyle = document.getElementById('style').value;

  // extra verification
  const style = p_change.style
  const findPropertyArr = Object.keys(style).filter(key => key === property)
  if (findPropertyArr.length > 0) {
    p_change.style[`${property}`] = `${newStyle}`;
    document.getElementById('error').remove();
  } else {
    p_change.innerHTML += '<p id="error" style="color:red">Invalid property name</span>'
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="p-change">Change my style like you love</p>
      <input id="property" value="" placeholder="Enter Property">
    <input id="style" value="" placeholder="Enter New Style">
      <button id="change">Change</button>
```

Comment: it works with let. But let has other use cases. You basically use `let` when you will change the value of that variable. For eg `let errorMessage = ' Some error ' ` and then further down in your code `if (a> b) { errorMessage = ' Different error ' } `

Answer (score -1):

selected nodes has `style` property with css properties in it.

```js
let node = document.querySelector('#someid')
node.style.color = 'red'
node.style.fontSize = '40px'
```