# How do i change one of the classes in an element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

If i have the library materialize and an element "h1", how do i change only its background color "black" to "white" using javascript? For example using a button.

```
<h1 class="black red-text">Test</h1>
```

Comment: Hi Quak, we'd need to see your attempt so far. You won't learn anything if we just give you the answer! [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241915/how-to-change-css-property-using-javascript) might help you though.

Comment: @TheBlacksmith Sorry, i will keep that in mind for the further posts. You're right I won't learn anything by getting the straight answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function and a `white` class. Inside the function use `document.getElementsByClassName` . Since `document.getElementsByClassName` is a collection so you need to use index like `[0]` to access it

```js
function changeColor() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("black")[0].classList.add('white')

}
```

```css
.white {
  background: white !important;
}

.black {
  background: black;
}

.red-text {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="black red-text">Test</h1>
<button onclick='changeColor()'>Change Color</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Give the element an id:

```
<h1 id="test" class="black red-text">Test</h1>
```

Then you can select it like the following:

```
var el = document.getElementById('test');
```

You can then just remove the class black with this code:

```
el.classList.remove('black');
```

And append the new class:

```
el.classList.add('white');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer.

Select the element using `document. getElementById`

and on button click

You can use title.classList.toggle("white"); to toggle given class.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('btn');
const title = document.getElementById('title');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  title.classList.toggle("white");
});
```

```css
.red-text {
  color: red;
}

.black {
  background-color: #000;
}

.white {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title" class="black red-text">Test</h1>
<button id="btn">Change Bg</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach that keeps things neat and tidy in terms of Materialize conventions could be to add or remove classnames, and thus triggering pre-existing styles. Note, you may need a more specific selector if you have multiple elements that share the class:

```
document.querySelector('h1.black').classList.add('white');
```

Materialize already has a vast array of [colour classes](https://materializecss.com/color.html#palette) so no need to create new ones.

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/XW):

And just for clarification:

`document.querySelector('h1.black')` - this finds the element with a matching class. You could also use ID to be more specific, while 
`.classList` retrieves all the classes applied to that element (in this case `.black` and `.red-text`) and `.add('white')` - well, that adds the class you state in the brackets.

Comment: So if i add the white class, the black one will be removed automatically?

Comment: It won't be removed, but  it will be overridden: https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/XW

Answer (score 1):

Hope this resolves your problem. just check the condition whether the class already exist if not add it.

```js
let h1 = document.querySelector(".red-text");
let btn = document.querySelector("#btn");


function changeColor(){
    if(h1.classList.contains("black")){
      h1.classList.remove("black");
      h1.classList.add("white"); 
    }else{
         h1.classList.add("black");
      h1.classList.remove("white"); 
    }
}

btn.addEventListener("click", changeColor);
```

```css
.black{
  background: black;
  color: red
}

.white{
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="black red-text">Test</h1>

<button id="btn">Change Color</button>
```

Comment: Edited the Answer. Please check it now.