# How to write this sentence correct JS

Tags: javascript, colors

I have 2 variables and i need to make this as a color. For example:

```
table1.style.cssText = "color: textcolor; background-color: bgcolor; "
```

where bgcolor and textcolor - variables with color value (red/black for example)

Comment: [How to change CSS property using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15241915)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a template literal.

```
table1.style.cssText = `color: ${textcolor}; background-color: ${bgcolor}; "
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inject variables into a string using a template literal string:

```
const textColor = 'white';
const bgColor = 'black';

table1.style.cssText = `color: ${textColor}; background-color: ${bgColor};`;
```

Demo:

```js
const msg = 'hello';
const msg2 = 'world';

console.log(`${msg} ${msg2}!!!`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also assign the values manually:

```js
const textColor = 'white';
const bgColor = 'black';

table1.style.color = textColor;
table1.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
```