# Does anyone know how to disable a SVG using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I've been trying to use something in JS like:

```
getElementById("dartboard").style.pointer-events = "none";
```

However, this does not work and the = has a red underline. Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241915/how-to-change-css-property-using-javascript

Comment: how are u selecting the svg in css ?

Comment: #dartboard svg {
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attribute names need to written in **camelCase** like so:

`pointer-events` => `pointerEvents`

```html
<svg id="dartboard" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" fill="red" stroke="green"/>
</svg>

<script>
  let dartboard = document.getElementById("dartboard");
  dartboard.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert('click');
  })

  dartboard.style.strokeWidth = 10;
  dartboard.style.pointerEvents = "none";
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change the css properties from javascript, as it is described here:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

```
var obj = document.getElementById("container");
obj.style.pointer-events = "none";
```

Comment: when I use this code the = has a red line underneath it and the code won't work